# Multiple fields count and sum using pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have four fields with int type data as well as null in data set , so i need to calculate the number of fields with data,i.e for suppose if first and third column has null values and second and fourth has integer values output is 2. 
second thing i need sum of those fields too,like in above example the output is 2

**Input**

```
null null null null
1    3    5    null 
null null 8    5
```

**Output:**

```
0    null 
3    9
2    13
```

Comment: i need row level count and sum for those fields

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post sample data and the script you have written.

Comment: using ternary statement to achieve this 

 so basically in output first column should return number of "no-null" values present in that row of that four fields and second column should return their sum.
but in ternary statement you can use only one column at a time but here i need to compare like all four fields...  (fl is null ? 0 :1 ) is fine but ((F1 AND F2 ) is null ? 0: 1) is not working

Comment: input                           output
  a        b        c       d    count     sum

 null    null     null    null    0       null

  1       3        5       null     3        9

 null     null     8        5      2        13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example how to do it

```
A = LOAD 'data.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (f1, f2, f3, f4);

B = FOREACH A GENERATE
    ( f1 IS NULL ? 0 : 1 ) AS f1_validity,
    ( f2 IS NULL ? 0 : 1 ) AS f2_validity,
    ( f3 IS NULL ? 0 : 1 ) AS f3_validity,
    ( f4 IS NULL ? 0 : 1 ) AS f4_validity;

C = FOREACH B GENERATE 
    f1_validity + f2_validity + f3_validity + f4_validity AS valid_field_cnt;
```

I hope I understand your problem correctly.

I just did the same right now :)

```
A = LOAD 'SO/null_data2.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (f1, f2, f3, f4);
DESCRIBE A;

--DUMP A;

B = FOREACH A GENERATE
    ( f1 IS NULL ? 0 : 1 ) AS f1_validity,
    ( f2 IS NULL ? 0 : 1 ) AS f2_validity,
        ( f3 IS NULL ? 0 : 1 ) AS f3_validity,
        ( f4 IS NULL ? 0 : 1 ) AS f4_validity,
    ( f1 IS NULL ? 0 : f1 ) AS f1,
    ( f2 IS NULL ? 0 : f2 ) AS f2,
        ( f3 IS NULL ? 0 : f3 ) AS f3,
        ( f4 IS NULL ? 0 : f4 ) AS f4;
DESCRIBE B;

C = FOREACH B GENERATE 
    f1_validity + f2_validity + f3_validity + f4_validity AS not_null_cnt,
    f1 + f2 + f3 + f4 AS sum;
DESCRIBE C;
DUMP C;
```

Comment: yes, i have been doing this but thing is it has to compare all four fields at same time and return "0" if all four fields have "null" values, return "1" if only one of them have no-null value and return "2" if only two of them have no-null values and  so on........

Comment: input                           output
  a        b        c       d    count     sum

 null    null     null    null    0       null

  1       3        5       null     3        9

 null     null     8        5      2        13

Comment: so basically  in output first column should return number of "no-null" values present in that row of that four fields and second column should return their sum

Answer (score 0):

```
A = LOAD 'test8.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (a,b,c,d);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE ( a is null ? 0 : 1 ) AS a1,
                       ( b is null ? 0 : 1 ) AS b1,
                       ( c is null ? 0 : 1 ) AS c1,
                       ( d is null ? 0 : 1 ) AS d1,
                       ( a is null ? 0 : a ) AS a,
                       ( b is null ? 0 : b ) AS b,
                       ( c is null ? 0 : c ) AS c,
                       ( d is null ? 0 : d ) AS d;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE a1 + b1 + c1 + d1 as field_count,
                       ((a + b + c + d) == 0 ? null : (a + b + c + d)) as field_sum;    
DUMP C;
```

**Output**

[image: Field Count and Field Sum]

Comment: You were faster by 17min :) I just did the same (added to my answer)